# Face detection in videos

Tags: computer-vision, machine-learning, face-detection

I have to detect faces in videos using machine learning methods like SVM,
I have to build it from scratch not using any inbuilt face detectors.My time limit is like 15hours from now.Can I get any valuable suggestions on how can I begin and proceed?
Thank you

Comment: Face detection in blurry, moving pictures from scratch? **In 15 hours?** How many experienced face recognition engineers are on your team? 5 or more?

Comment: Building this in 14 hours is one thing. Being able to defend its design and operation is another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have 15 hours I would built it on a well known 
easy to understand algorithm like [Viola and Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework), which uses weak binary classifiers and combines them to detect faces. It is relativily fast algorithm that runs in realtime.

You can get more information on the algorithm in the following stack exchange [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808434/how-does-the-viola-jones-face-detection-method-work)

Comment: for now I built a face detector using HOG features and svm classifier,I have to extend it to videos,thanks for suggestion